# Need help designing a regex to select all characters between '|' and '|' if the first '|' is followed be a space?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

For example, in this string: `--|-------| d[Verse 1] e|--------|-3-` it would select `d[Verse 1] e` (and the space behind the d), and in `--|-0----0---2--| E|--------|--` it would select `E`, (and the space behind the E.)

The only known constant is that the first `|` will always be followed by a space. If it's followed by anything other than a space, such as `-`, as in `|-` a selection should not be started.

So a regular expression that selects ALL characters between two `|`'s if and only if the first `|` is followed by a space.

One more example for clarity: `-----|-----|-----| [Ouro] e|-------|---|--------| Cadd9  Ce|---|---` should be formated to `-----|-----|-----||-------|---|--------||---|---` after I have selected and removed all instances.

Comment: There is no space between `|` and `[Ouro]` ?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my part. Edited

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
/(\| +[^\|]+)+/g
```

See http://regexr.com/3d5go

Then just replace each element's leading `|` like so:

```
var matches = oldString
  .match(/(\| +[^\|]+)+/g)
  .map(function(el){ return el.replace('| ','') })
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to escape the pipe symbol in the character class

Comment: Depends on the regex. In javascript you do.

Comment: I'm 100% certain you don't need to escape the pipe symbol in a character class for javascript flavor of regex.  This demo works just the same as yours: http://regexr.com/3d5gr

Comment: Gotcha, emphasis on character class and not on escaping pipe symbol.  Rather than commit vagaries to memory (like escaping the first pipe in your example but not the second), I'd prefer to just escape everywhere as it's less mental overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

**Regex:** `/\|\s+[^|]+/g` and replace with `|`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iP8iB3/2)

Comment: This is nearly perfect, but can it exclude the first | ?

Comment: Since lookbehind is not supported in Javascript, one approach is to capture the `lookbehind` part and replace it which I did. Match should be replaced by `|` in order to restore peace :-). That way we finally get the result. Check the demo and the substitution part.